# WPF C#: MVVM - Passing on the Sudoku from ViewModel -> View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So, I have a question about MVVM+WPF: Currently, I have a Sudoku working and I managed to generate a Sudoku the way I like to have one in WPF.

Sudoku WPF Image from my Application

[image]

The problem is that the Grid is being created by some code I've written in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file and I think it should be in a ViewModel. Code in question in the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace SodukoWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SudokoGameDesu sudokuAdapter;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sudokuAdapter = new SudokoGameDesu();


            CreateDynamicWPFGrid();
        }

        private void CreateDynamicWPFGrid()
        {
            // Create 9 rows & columns
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                // Create column
                sudokuGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            ... etc.
```

Imho, CreateDynamicWPFGrid() should be moved to my ViewModel. At least that's where I think this code fits the most.

```
namespace SodukoWPF.ViewModels
{
    public class SudokoPresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // TODO get .xaml.cs code in here

        public SudokoPresenter()
        {
            //CreateDynamicWPFGrid();
        }
```

In the CreateDynamicWPFGrid() method I use sudokuGrid, a field from my .xaml so my code knows to which grid.Children my textBoxes/Blocks should be added too.

```
<Grid x:Name="contentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="570" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500">
        <Grid x:Name="sudokuGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="488">
        </Grid>
```

Now, this grid is not accessible from outside the .xaml.cs code (of course). So at this point, my approach of generating my own xaml (because, I don't think this can be done through only xaml + bindings) is giving me some question marks whether I'm applying MVVM right or not.

Theoretically the ViewModel should not know about the View, but I still think that the generated .xaml should be in my SudokuPresenter - ViewModel and not in my .xaml.cs which preferably should just be empty I think.

I also still haven't figured out how to get the SudokuGrid to my ViewModel, but chances are my approach to MVVM is faulty to begin with or misunderstood on my part.

Hope someone can help me out and this post or more or less makes sense on my dilemmas =)

(MVVM approach in regards to generating my own .xaml + how to access sudokuGrid if I'm doing it more or less right)

Comment: I feel you didn't understand MVVM pattern. You definitely should not have any UI concerns in your ViewModel. Your Sudoku data should be in your ViewModel, and the grid itself in your xaml. One thing wwhere you're right is about your xaml.cs : it should be empty and you should use templates or a custom control to build your sudoku grid with binding.

Comment: The thing about the Grid is that it gets generated, so I'm not sure how to bind the Sudoku to the Grid. Also the Grid uses 81 Rectangles, 9 Black rectangles, 81 TextBoxes/TextBlocks and I'm not sure how to get that in the Grid without writing a shit ton of .xaml. I figured generating would be the easiest/smartest way to do it, but that could be me not properly knowing how to do WPF & xaml

E: Grid/Sudoku gets generated (+ passed on to the View) every time the application starts, it is also supposed to get generated again when the Reset button is pressed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm happy to see there are still new users that take time to make their question be readable and explain it well! Now the problem: Why not build an object called cell, that will hold all the cell data (value, location, etc.) and fin your ViewModel create a collection of cells that you will fill an uniform grid with, using bindings?

Comment: That actually sounds like a great idea that didn't occur to me, mostly because of my inexperience with WPF & Xaml tbh. Just getting me thinking towards this direction should prevent the whole issue I have right now so thanks! =). Just need to google and figure out how to get those custom cells working, but I think I can get it done.

Comment: The idea of generating a grid by code is useful when your grid is not always the same, this is not the case so why not writing your grid in xaml. When data changes, the grid don't need to be generated when you start a new game, only your data changes. You also can create your bindings by code if you prefer to keep going with code generated grid : [MSDN - How to: Create a Binding in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do you have a large control that, at the smallest level, is a large number of UI elements that, as a group, are repeated 81x in nine sets of nine?  Then create two bloody user controls--one that's a cell containing the large number of UI elements that consist of that smallest level group, and one that's a grid of 9x9 of the former cells.  Throw nine of the latter into your window and you're (almost) done.  DRY applies to UI as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of MVVM (and wpf in general) is slightly different that what you had shown.

Let me provide you with a breakdown of how each element of MVVM should function in your case:

1. The Model
   The model is pretty much your data holders. It's objects, that contain the information about crucial elements of your program, that will further be used and processed in ViewModel(s).

In your case, that would be, in the most basic case, the cell Class and the Grid class. 
The Cell class would contain basic cell info: value, location.
The Grid class would contain a collection of cells, as well as methods for ex. For retrieving cell x that's left to cell y, Retrieving cells that are contained in a box(the 3x3 sudoku square), etc.

2. The ViewModel

This would contain your program logic. Now, don't get it wrong - this should ONLY contain things like what happens when you input a value into the cell in the GUI - for example run the evaluator for the correctness of the whole grid.

This should also contain the Grid class itself - so it can be referenced by the GUI.

3. The View:

This is mostly your XAML. As far as you don't dwelve too much into things like IoC containers, dependency injection (which I think you shouldn't for your first actual MVVM program), your xaml.cs (code-behind of view) will in most cases stay without any change.

The view could contain a UniformGrid, that has a certain template for how each cell will look like, and that uniformgrid would be bound to the Collection of cells - that would sit in your Grid model class.

Now, most people without MVVM background will go like: "But do I get to name them? How will I reference those abstract, dynamically created cell classes?"

This way, the UI would create all cells on its own, and each of them would be assigned a certain cell class automatically, so it WILL know that the value you just input will be stored in the X instance of the cell class.

Your goal is to devise methods/class structure, that will allow you to do any desired operation easily and "indirectly" (ex. A method that sits inside the Game class and checks whether all cells in a box (3x3 Grid) are input according to the rules of sudoku.

I hope you grasped the concept, Feel free to ask any questions, and I will be happy to produce example codes to explain these certain concepts better.

Comment: I think the things you've told me will help me along now and give me a good place to start. I feel pretty stupid about forgetting to build a proper Model Class. E: I mean. There is a Model class, but it's only an Adapter for the actual GameClass that generates the Sudoku and checks whether a variable at the proper x, y place is wrong/right. So I only need to build the application in such a way that the MVVM structure is working properly. Having a Cell class and maybe/probably also the Grid class should still help a lot, solve my MVVM problems and all that stuff so thanks ;d

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but I still think you might need some guidance. I will try to update my answer with examples when I have free time tonight.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll still be working on this application for today and I'll check on this post later, especially if I get stuck somehow and google can't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Supervising controller pattern as like follows

1 ) Define interface IView in which ViewModel will talk to View with the required method

```
public interface IView 
{
    void CreateDynamicWPFGrid();
}
```

2)  Inherit code behind View from your IView and implement IView.CreateDynamicWPFGrid() method

```
  public partial class View : IView 
{
    public void CreateDynamicWPFGrid() 
    {  
        // implement here your custom view logic using standard code behind; 
    }
}
```

3 ) Add property of type IView to your viewModel

```
    public class ViewModel 
{
    public IView View { get; set; }
}
```

4 ) Set View property on viewmodel to instance of View as IView e.g. in code behind DataContext.View = this as IView; or in Caliburn you can use IScreen.OnViewAttached override method)

```
public View()
{

    (DataContext as ViewModel).View = this as IView;
} 

public void CreateDynamicWPFGrid() 
{  
    // implement here your custom view logic using standard code behind; 
}
```

5 ) In your viewmodel call IView.CreateDynamicWPFGrid()

```
    public class ViewModel 
{
    public IView View { get; set; }

    public void CreateDynamicWPFGrid() 
    {
        if (View == null)
        {
          return;
       } 
        View.CreateDynamicWPFGrid()
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is an MVVM approach, it just pushes his (partially incorrect/less proper) approaches and tries to make them MVVM-ish. What he should do instead, he should restructure his whole application and do it from the base up, building proper Models for his data.

Comment: Agreed with Kamil, while this would theoretically solve my problem and be an easy solution. It wouldn't properly solve my MVVM structuring problem, which was the real problem I was dealing with/wondering about. Thanks anyway though ;-)